# CakePhp 3 Save data in belongsTo

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So, i have problem with saving data to DB

Model Table is
...

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
```

...

I want to store new Address in row and data structure is

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Address) {

    'type' => (int) 1,
    'Users' => [
        'user_id' => '9'
    ],
    'short_name' => 'Test',
    'long_name' => 'test',
    'additional_name' => 'test',
```

I have tried in controller

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $address = $this->Addresses->patchEntity($address, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Users.user_id']]);
                if ($this->Addresses->save($address)) {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('The address has been saved.'));
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('The address could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
```

And in my template view this is input field

```
echo $this->Form->input('Users.user_id', ['type' => 'select', 'options' => $groups, 'class' => 'form-control']);
echo $this->Form->input('short_name', ['class' => 'form-control']);
echo $this->Form->input('long_name', ['class' => 'form-control']);
```

So, what can I do? How to reorganize data stucture?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the CakePHP <= 2.x styled naming conventions for your inputs, that's not how it works with CakePHP 3.x anymore.

Please refer to the docs on how to create inputs for associated data:

**[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Inputs for Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data)**

You have to use the appropriate property name of the association, just as it appears in the entity when reading data. For `belongsTo` associations, this is by default the singular, underscored variant of the association alias, so in your case `user`, ie

```
echo $this->Form->input('user.user_id', [
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $groups,
    'class' => 'form-control'
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations > BelongsTo Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving BelongsTo Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongsto-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Field Naming Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions)**